# Is is thread-safe to modify different keys of common hash between threads?

Tags: ruby, concurrency

Is it thread safe to share Ruby Hash between threads and modify it in each thread, having guarantee **each thread modifies different key** (appends new hash with undetermined, before execution, number of keys to it)?

I know it's not thread-safe to do it, if threads modify the same key, however, I am not sure if it's safe if they modify different keys.

e.g. below is an example program that might illustrate the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

array = [*1..100]
hash = {}
array.each do |element|
    hash[element] = {}
end
threads = []
array.each do |element|
    threads << Thread.new do
        random = rand(1..100)
        hash_new_keys = [*0..random]
        hash[element] = {}
        hash_new_keys.each do |key|
            hash[element][key] = rand(1..10)
        end
    end
end
threads.each(&:join)
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how your data structure might look like and how the threads are going to change it? Did you consider something – like a Mutex – to guarantee this to be thread safe

Comment: ok, I added example code. I considered mutex, but it slows down my application significantly, that's why I am trying to figure out, if it's safe do it without mutexes or any kind of synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use MRI then its thread-safe to modify array/hash in different threads. GIL guarantees that only one thread is active at the time.

Here's 5 threads sharing one Array object. Each thread pushes nil into the Array 1000 times:

```
array = []

5.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    1000.times do
      array << nil
    end
  end
end.each(&:join)

puts array.size


$ ruby pushing_nil.rb
5000

$ jruby pushing_nil.rb
4446

$ rbx pushing_nil.rb
3088
```

> Because MRI has a GIL, even when there are 5 threads running at once,
>   only one thread is active at a time. In other words, things aren't
>   truly parallel. JRuby and Rubinius don't have a GIL, so when you have
>   5 threads running, you really have 5 threads running in parallel
>   across the available cores.
>
> On the parallel Ruby implementations, the 5 threads are stepping
>   through code that's not thread-safe. They end up interrupting each
>   other and, ultimately, corrupting the underlying data.

Ref https://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/8085491-nobody-understands-the-gil

Comment: In other words, might as well use one thread and not worry about code breaking under jruby :)

Comment: Can you just please answer, if that what you described, also applies to example I supplied (added on edition)?

Comment: I am just trying to make sure, that pushing elements to array is analogous to modifications of different keys in a hash.

Comment: @thinktanker same applies to all MRI internal data structures as well as hash. I would advise you to just check it if you are not sure

Comment: @MartinZinovsky ok, I am not quite sure how to check it easily, but I suppose any write operation is not completely safe, so after all i put mutex locks around every modification to shared data structure, just in case (it does not cost that much, as I thought it does)